# Скрипт php, который считал бы сумму цифр числа введенного пользователем из консоли

Tags: php

Пытаюсь делать:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $argc; $i++) {
    $sum += $argc[$i];
}

echo $sum;
```

Но это не правильно.
Нужно, чтобы в консоли выполнялся данный файл с параметром (введёнными пользователем числами), например `php file.php 235`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: непонятно.... ввод 235 а вывод должен быть 10? `Но это не правильно` - что конкретно подразумевается под этим?

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i < strlen($argv[1]); $i++) {
    $sum += (int)$argv[1][$i];
}` ?

Comment: Алексей, сработало. Спасибо. Только поясните пожалуйста мне почему $argv[1]

Comment: почему не $argv[o]. В массиве ж с индекса 0 начинается.

Comment: @Sven Первый аргумент $argv[0] всегда содержит имя файла запущенного скрипта. вы же пишите `php` и дальше что-то.......file.php и 234...... первый аргумент и второй......Логично Правда?))

Comment: я так и подумал сразу, но потом засомневался так как мы ж работаем именно с аргументами(числами), который вводит пользователь. Тогда всё ясно. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если цифры пишутся слитно (числом), то их нужно разделить:

```
if (isset($argv[1])) {

    $numbers = trim($argv[1]);
    $numbers_list = str_split($numbers);

    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($numbers_list as $num) {

        $num = intval($num);
        $sum += $num;
    }

    echo $sum;
}
```

Comment: а почему trim($argv[1]) а не trim($argv[0]) ?

Comment: Потому что в `$argv[0]` будет храниться строка `file.php` (имя исполняемого файла). Проверить просто: `var_dump($argv);`

Comment: да, спасибо..я понял.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такое простое решение.

```
unset($argv[0]);
echo array_sum(array_filter($argv, 'is_numeric'));
```

Comment: Первый аргумент $argv[0] всегда содержит имя файла запущенного скрипта.

Comment: @pank, спасибо, добавлю в ответ